# JavaScript: How to open a link in a new tab without window.open()?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have an href that I need to open in a new tab, and can't use an anchor tag because it's from within a webgl context. The following accomplishes this:

```js
window.open(href, "_blank");
```

However, it comes with the large caveat that the new tab shares a runtime/process with the original, which for a heavy web-app leads to resource problems.

I tried creating an invisible anchor tag and clicking it via JS as a workaround:

```js
const anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.setAttribute("href", href);
anchor.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

anchor.click();
```

but Chrome blocks this as a "popup".

There must be some way to do this, surely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a new tab in separate thread with JavaScript? (chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574000/how-to-open-a-new-tab-in-separate-thread-with-javascript-chrome)

Comment: Sort of, but @Finn Lyonn's solution below is much cleaner and more appropriate to my use-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, the "noopener" feature runs the window in a seperate process
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#noopener

```
let d = window.open('https://www.google.com/', 'name', 'noopener=yes');
```

with noopener, d would now be null